# Multiple one line assignments with malloc in c

Tags: c, memory, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

Suppose the below statement:

```
int *numbers, *inverse;
numbers = inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

I am curious to know what is going on here - I know it is right to left, so first the memory for `inverse` is being allocated. Then I set `numbers` equal to `inverse`, will that mean that the memory location of `numbers` will be the same as `inverse`? Or does it allocate the same amount of memory at locations `&numbers` and `&inverse`?

For example, if I do something like `inverse[i] = 5` will that mean that `numbers[i] == 5`?

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have:

```
int *numbers, *inverse;
numbers = inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

That's the same as writing:

```
int *inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
int *numbers = inverse;
```

The variable `numbers` simply has a copy of the pointer that is in `inverse` — it points to the same place.  However, you might be about to iterate through the array with one pointer while returning the other from the function, which could be a good reason for having the two copies.

There's a single memory allocation; there will need to be a single call to `free()` to release the allocated memory.  The value passed to `free()` will be the same as the original value assigned to either `inverse` or `numbers`.

You also ask:

> If I do something like `inverse[i] = 5` will that mean that `numbers[i] == 5`?

If you've not changed the value stored in either `inverse` or `numbers`, and if `i` is in the range `0` .. `(n-1)`, then after the assignment, the equality will hold.  The pointers are the same (same type, same value), so indexing them produces the same result.  It also means `inverse[i] == numbers[i]` of course.

Answer (score 4):

The first job is to drop the `(int*)` cast which is superfluous (and such a scheme can even be harmful if the type is not built-in). This is one of the differences between C and C++.

`malloc(n * sizeof(int));` returns a pointer of type `void*`.

That pointer is assigned to `inverse`.

But the *expression* `inverse = malloc(n * sizeof(int))` has type `int*`. This therefore can then be validly assigned to `numbers`.

To be very clear, `malloc` is called exactly once, and therefore you should call `free` exactly once.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR, yes, both `inverse` and `numbers` point to same memory.

---

**Long answer:** On *why* part, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.16, *Assignment operators* <sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

> [...] An
>   assignment expression has the **value of the left operand after the assignment**, but is not
>   an lvalue. The type of an assignment expression is the **type the left operand would have
>   after lvalue conversion**.

So, as you have mentioned correctly, [for right-to-left associativity of the assignment operator `=`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), the evaluation looks like

```
numbers = ( inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int)) );
```

so, once `inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int))` is evaluated,

- The value of this expression is the value of `inverse` after the assignment
- Also, the type is as of the same type of `inverse`

(*and both are valid*) thus, the next evaluation is the same as

```
 numbers = inverse;
```

So, (*if you want*), you can break down the statements like

```
if ( (inverse = malloc(n * sizeof*inverse )) )  //error check, just saying
      numbers = inverse;
```

[and finally, if you're wondering why I removed the cast, see this discussion for more info on this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917)

Answer (score 3):

Only one chunk of memory has been allocated, and both `inverse` and `numbers` point to the same chunk.

We can verify this experimentally.

```
#include <assert>

int main() {
    int n = 100;
    int *numbers, *inverse;
    numbers = inverse = (int *)malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    numbers[0] = 10;
    inverse[0] = 20;

    // If numbers and inverse point to the same memory, then we would expect
    // that numbers[0] is now 20.
    assert(inverse[0] == 20);
    assert(numbers[0] == 20);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are allocating a single block of memory. That's the magic of pointers!

Comment: That's not a bit specific to pointers! `int i,k; i = k = 1;` is exactly the same!

Comment: No it's not. Your code declares two int variables and sets them equal to the same value. That's not the same thing as declaring two pointers to int and pointing them at the same int field in memory.

Comment: A pointer is not a reference! Both snippets assign the **value** of the LHS of the inner assignment to the lvalue of the next-outer assignment! The semantics of the values is completely unrelated.

Comment: You are correct when you say that the semantics of the values are not relevant to the functionality of the assignment operator. That's not what the OP is concerned about. The question was about the practical effect.

Comment: Has common sense really diminished that much? It is a simple injection: `a->b->c => a->c`

Answer (score 0):

Here you are allocating a single block of memory And storing the address in two pointers. So both the pointers will point to the same address

Answer (score -1):

In C, an assignment (`=`, `+=`, ...) is an operator like `+`, `-`, etc. It yields the value of the left hand side of the operator. See the standard [6.5.16p3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.16p3) They are right associative, evaluation order is:

```
numbers = ( inverse = malloc(n * sizeof(int)) );
```

(Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends or `void *` in general to pointers. It is not required in C and potentially harmful.)

So `number` gets the same **value** as `inverse`. Which is whatever the  `malloc` returned for the right assignment.

To emphasise: this is no way related to pointers:

```
int i, k;
i = k = 4;
```

is exactly the same principle.

Edit:

To state it clear (once more): The right hand side of an assignment **as for every operator** is evaluated exactly **once**. You would not expect `f(x) + g(x) + h(x)` to have `h` called twice either.

For the pointers: `malloc` returns a pointer to a memory block, both pointers have the same value, thus they point to the same memory block. As both have the same type, you may use both to access the memory block.

Comment: It is the same principle in the sense that shooting someone with a foam dart gun is the same principle as shooting them with an AK-47. In practice they have very different effects.

Comment: @RobertColumbia: Please elaborate! The effect is exactly the same: the value from the LHS of the inner assignement is used as RHS of the next.

Comment: The OP's question was about whether the result of his code would be the creation of two memory blocks or one. The assignment operator works from right to left on pointers in the same way that it works on ints, but a pointer is not an int. If you set a pointer equal to another pointer, you end up with two pointers pointing to the same location. Changing the value pointed to by one will (by definition) change the value pointed to by the other one. If you set an int equal to another int, you end up with two ints that have the same value. Changing one will have no effect on the other.

Comment: It should be clear what the effect is,a s I clearly state that `number` gets the same value as `inverse`. You confuse the semantics with the operator. Don't try to make these two different, otherwise next time OP will ask if `i = k = f(x);` is different and call `f` twice.